# data breakpoints in java/eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints

when developing C++ with VS you have this amazing feature of data breakpoints, which trigger when the data at a certain address in memory changes.

is there a similar feature when developing java in eclipse?

thanks!

edit: about the "suspend when value changes" feature: i have the impression that the execution must still reach the line where the breakpoint is. the thing is i want it to trigger anywhere as soon as the value changes.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can set a watchpoint on a field: put the cursor at the line where the field is being declared and select the menu `Run -> Toggle Watchpoint`
or just set a breakpoint by double-clicking at the left margin on that line.

You can change the properties of the watchpoint like `suspend on field access` or `suspend on field modification` after adding it. Just right-click on the watchpoint at the left margin and select `Breakpoint Properties...`

Search the help for watchpoint to get more information:

> A watchpoint is a special breakpoint that stops the execution of an application whenever the value of a given expression changes, without specifying where it might occur. ...

Comment: This is useful (and I +1'ed), but it's still not quite the answer to the question. This break on *any* instance of that declaration, not on a specific instance.

Comment: I only have the watchpoint option available when the field is not final.  How can I watch access to a final object?  (I want to see whenever an item is added to or retrieved from a map.)

Comment: that should have been another question... but strange, with Eclipse Mars there is no problem setting a watchpoint at a final variable (just tested with an ArrayList and a Path), but, no matter of final or not, this will not watch the contents of the object saved in the variable - it _only_ watches the content of the variable itself, that is, in your case, if the map instance is changed. You can put a breakpoint on the corresponding methods of the (Hash)Map and add a condition to check that `this` is the instance you want to watch.

Answer (score 6):

Using the Variable view:

- right click the field and select "Toggle Watchpoint", and then
- right click the same instance again and select "Instance breakpoints..." which allows you to restrict a specific breakpoint to a given instance.

Note that the performance is probably not as good as with a memory hardware breakpoint (like in VC++ for example).

Comment: Does this option still exist? In Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0) I am only able to set a thread filter in the breakpoint properties.

Answer (score 3):

Under breakpoint properties, you have the option of making it conditional and checking the radio button "Suspend when value changes".

Comment: thanks, but how exactly do i provide the object or a variable to that object which i want to monitor?

Comment: You enter that in the field below.  Granted, that's not the same as breaking whenever that variable changes, but if there's a bottleneck in which your program passes often, you can place such a breakpoint there and in theory break only when a certain value changes.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the Breakpoint and select `Breakpoint properties`.

In the opening screen, choose: `Conditional -> Suspend when value changes`

Comment: thanks, but how exactly do i provide the object or a variable to that object which i want to monitor?

Comment: in the field below the radio button, enter the variable name (something like this.foo). There's auto-completion available.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing would be editing the breakpoint properties. You could add conditions to check for distinct values. Another way could be adding a breakpoint to the setter method.

You can set the breakpoint properties by right-clicking on an already set breakpoint in the breakpoint view.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such generic feature in Eclipse. However, you can give some conditions to an existing breakpoint:

Add a breakpoint somewhere in your code. Then, in the "Breakpoint" view, right click on it, then choose "Breakpoint properties". In the panel, you can add a condition that must be verified to make the application stops on this breakpoint (for example `if (foo > 0)`).

This is not exactly what you want, but I do not think Eclipse provides such feature.