# Eclipse: Inline breakpoints

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jdi

Is there a way to set inline breakpoints (with a plugin) in the Eclipse IDE?

For example when multiple methods are called in the same line, is there a way to set a breakpoint for a specific method call in that line and not for the complete line?

```
foo(bar(), baz());
           ^
```

(In this example it would be possible to set a breakpoint at the definition of the method `baz`, but if it is called by other methods as well, then it might be annoying if you have to continue most of the time.)

If I understand it correctly, the Java Debug Interface would allow this, see [Location#codeIndex()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/Location.html#codeIndex--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo(bar(), 
    baz());
```

The easiest way to do this is to do a line break before baz() and place your breakpoint as normal on the line baz() is found on. In Java, surrounding a method call with a line break in this way, will not impact its evaluation.

[screenshot from eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDMn1.png)

### Update:

OP wants to select the invocation of baz and make a breakpoint on the evaluation of that expression itself without any extra conditions on your breakpoint or editing of the source code.

As far as I know that is not possible with the standard debugging tool shipped with Eclipse.

However, you can achieve this effect using [conditional breakpoints](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-condition_option.htm). In Eclipse, you make or select a breakpoint as normal, then access the conditional options in the Breakpoints View.

Access Breakpoint View through the menu item Window -> Show View -> Breakpoints. Once there, select or create your breakpoint, then check the conditional option. Then you must describe a conditional that suits your surrounding code and needs. Your breakpoint will trigger when the conditional is true. For example, by specifying the call-site line number or method name.

[Breakpoints View in Eclipse, with conditionals enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uVtK.png)

I based my answer on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14381894/5635639).

In my own example code I have the following setup:

```
a(){
  baz(); 
  m();
}

m(){
  foo(bar(), baz());
}
```

and my breakpoint is positioned in baz(). Adding the conditional statement

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName().equals("m")
```

to my breakpoint means that it triggers only when baz() is called from m(), not from a().

Comment: Yes thank you, that would work, but in this specific case I would like to not have to change the source code just to be able to debug it better.

Comment: You may be able to do what you want with conditioned breakpoints. Here is a [link](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-condition_option.htm) to the documentation: in general you go to the menu Window-> Show View -> Breakpoints, make a line breakpoint as normal, either on your foo(bar(), baz()) -line or inside of baz(), and describe a suitable condition for it to trigger. It is impossible to me to give you further suggestions on the conditions without more information about your program.

Comment: Thank you very much. These workarounds are good, but I am looking for a general solution for the described problem. Therefore I don't have specific code to share, it could apply to any, but it is also not a problem for me if there is (at the moment) no direct solution for this.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand you correctly: you want to select the invocation of baz and make a breakpoint on the evaluation of that expression itself without any extra conditions on your breakpoint or editing of the source code? As far as I know that is not possible with the standard debugging tool shipped with Eclipse. However, using conditionals you can do that, and write your [conditions against the surrounding code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381446/conditional-breakpoint-by-caller-in-java-eclipse), for example, by specifying the call-site line number or method name.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am looking for. I guess your workaroud is close enough, would you mind writing it in a separate answer or updating your existing one?